# Another way to write least prime factor.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

## My Problem

### Definition

Let $L:{\Bbb N }\backslash \{ 1\} \to {\Bbb N }\backslash \{ 1\}$ such that $L(n) = \text{least prime factor } p \text{ such that } 2 \leqslant p \leqslant n$.

### Proving or Disproving

Prove or disprove that $$L(n) = \min(L(a),L(b))$$ where $n = ab$ and $1<a,b<n$ and $a,b \in {{\Bbb Z}^ + }$.

### Ideas

$a$ and $b$ are factors of $n$ and see who is smaller using the $\min$ function, but also $\min$ can be used if both numbers are the same, i.e. $\min (a,a) = a$. So, it seems reasonable that we need to find the least prime factor of each factor of $n$. But I don't know how to prove this.

### Proof (Thanks for Keith) [Update]

WLOG, let $a \leqslant b$, and by the Unique Factorization,

> Let $a = \prod {{p_i}}$ and $b = \prod {{q_j}}$, then $n = ab = \prod {{p_i}\prod {{q_j}} }$

$\Rightarrow L(n) = L(\prod {{p_i}} \prod {{q_j}})$. Since $L(a) = p_1 = p$ and $L(b) = q_1 = q$ and $\Rightarrow p|n$ and $q|n$. Therefore, just take the least one.

Hence $$L(n) = \min(L(a),L(b))$$

### Aplications

This is useful to easily compute the least prime factor for some numbers. This is because the factors of n have have least prime factors in common. Some examples: $L(2421) = L(9 \cdot 269) = \min(L(9), L(269)) = \min (3, 269) = 3$.

Comment: Hint: By the unique factorization theorem, $a=\prod p_i$ and $b=\prod q_j$. Also, $n=ab=\prod p_i \cdot \prod q_j$ where $p_i,q_j$ are primes. Apply the $L$ function to $a,b,n$ and you should see the desired result.

Comment: But does $p_i$ and $p_j$ need to have exponents, Keith Backman? I'm talking about this b/c of the **Unique Factorization Theorem**.

Comment: The presence or absence of exponents will not affect what prime in each case is largest or smallest. If exponents are omitted, then we can just state that $p_i$ not be unique, i.e. if $7^4$ were part of the factorization, you could consider simply that $7$ was a prime factor, or you could write out $p_i\dots 7\cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \dots p_k$. If it so happened that $7$ were the smallest prime factor in a number, which way you choose to represent the factorization does not affect the choice of $7$ as the smallest.

Comment: Thank you, Keith!

Comment: $L$ should have domain $\mathbb N \setminus  \{1\}$

Comment: A fundamental theorem in Number Theory is that if $a,b,c$ are non-zero integers and $a|(bc)$  while $\gcd (a,b)=1$ then $a|c$ (implying unique fqctorization). For your Q  you only need the case where $c$ is prime, from which it is immediate that $any$ prime  $c$ divides $ ab$ iff $(c|a $ or $ c|b)$.